# Check if an indexed array in bash is sparse or dense

Tags: arrays, bash, sparse-matrix

I have a dynamically generated, indexed array in bash and want to know whether it is **sparse** or **dense**.
An array is sparse iff there are unset indices before the last entry. Otherwise the array is dense.

The check should work in every case, even for empty arrays, very big arrays (exceeding ARG_MAX when expanded), and of course arrays with arbitrary entries (for instance null entries or entries containing `*`, `\`, spaces, and linebreaks). The latter should be fairly easy, as you probably don't want to expand the values of the array anyways.

Ideally, the check should be efficient and portable.

Here are some basic test cases to check your solution.
Your check can use the hard-coded global variable name `a` for compatibility with older bash versions. For bash 4.3 and higher you may want to use `local -n isDense_array="$1"` instead, so that you can specify the array to be checked.

```
isDense() {
  # INSERT YOUR CHECK HERE
  # if array `a` is dense, return 0 (success)
  # if array `a` is sparse, return any of 1-255 (failure) 
}
test() {
  isDense && result=dense || result=sparse 
  [[ "$result" = "$expected" ]] ||
  echo "Test in line $BASH_LINENO failed: $expected array considered $result"
}

expected=dense
a=(); test
a=(''); test
a=(x x x); test

expected=sparse
a=([1]=x); test
a=([1]=); test
a=([0]=x [2]=x); test
a=([4]=x [5]=x [6]=x); test
a=([0]=x [3]=x [4]=x [13]=x); test
```

To benchmark your check, you can use

```
a=($(seq 9999999))
time {
  isDense
  unset 'a[0]'; isDense
  a[0]=1; unset 'a[9999998]'; isDense
  a=([0]=x [9999999999]=x); isDense
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Approach

Non-empty, dense arrays have indices from `0` to `${#a[*]}-1`. Due to the pigeonhole principle, the *last* index of a sparse array must be greater or equal `${#a[@]}`.

#### Bash Script

To get the last index, we assume that the list of indices `${!a[@]}` is in ascending order. Bash's manual does not specify any order, but (at least for bash 5 and below) the implementation guarantees this order (in the source code file `array.c` search for `array_keys_to_word_list`).

```
isDense() {
  [[ "${#a[*]}" = 0 || " ${!a[*]}" == *" $((${#a[*]}-1))" ]]
}
```

For small arrays this works very well. For huge arrays the check is a bit slow because of the `${!a[*]}`. The benchmark from the question took 9.8 seconds.

#### Loadable Bash Builtin

The approach in this answer only needs the *last* index. But bash only allows to extract *all* indices using `${!a[*]}` which is unnecessary slow. Internally, bash knows what the last index is. So if you wanted, you could write a loadable builtin that has access to bash's internal data structures.

Of course this is not a really practical solution. If the performance really did matter that much, you shoudn't use a bash script. Nevertheless, I wrote such a builtin for the fun of it.

[Loadable bash builtin](https://github.com/schaetzc/bash-loadable-is-array-dense)

The space and time complexity of above builtin is indepent of the size and structure of the array. Checking `isdense a` should be as fast as something like `b=1`.

Comment: `isDense() { local IFS=,; (( i = (${!a[*]}), i && i == ${#a[*]} - 1 )); }` would be slightly faster in extreme cases.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For the benchmark this uses 9.399s instead of 9.586s. But it also causes syntax errors for `a=()` and fails the test `a=('')`.

Comment: I love that you wrote a builtin. I keep meaning to experiment with builtins, they seem like a great (read: totally impractical, power-user-only) feature that doesn't get a lot of use.

Comment: might be useful to have a builtin that returns the array's max(index); or perhaps the `nth from the end` index (eg, would allow traversal of indices in reverse - as opposed to printing/sorting ${!arr[@]});

Comment: @markp-fuso Retrieving the last array index is easy. Writing a `maxindex` builtin was actually my first plan, but then I thought, why stop there if I can implement everything at once. `nth from the end` on the other hand, would require iteration inside the builtin and is not required for this task.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** (re)ran tests in an Ubuntu 20 VM (much better times than previous tests in a `cygwin/bash` env; times are closer to those reported by Socowi)

---

**NOTE:** I populated my array with 10 million entries (`{0..9999999}`).

Using the same assumption as Socowi ...

> To get the last index of an array, we assume that the list of indices ${!a[@]} is in ascending order. Bash's manual does not specify any order, but (at least for bash 5 and below) the implementation guarantees this order

... we can make the same assumption about the output from `typeset -p a`, namely, output is ordered by index.

---

**Finding the last index:**

```
$ a[9999999]='[abcdef]'
$ typeset -p a | tail -c 40
9999998]="9999998" [9999999]="[abcdef]")
```

**1st attempt** using `awk` to strip off the last index:

```
$ typeset -p a | awk '{delim="[][]"; split($NF,arr,delim); print arr[2]}'
9999999
```

This is surprisingly slow (> 3.5 **minutes** for `cygwin/bash`) while running at 100% (single) cpu utilization and eating up ~4 GB of memory.

**2nd attempt** using `tail -c` to limit the data fed to `awk`:

```
$ typeset -p a | tail -c 40 | awk '{delim="[][]"; split($NF,arr,delim); print arr[2]}'
9999999
```

This came in at a (relatively) blazing speed of ~1.6 seconds (`ubuntu/bash`).

**3rd attempt** saving last array value in local variable before parsing with `awk`

**NOTES:**

- as Socowi's pointed out (in comments), the contents of the last element could contain several characters (spaces, brackets, single/double quotes, etc) that make parsing quite complicated
- one workaround is to save the last array value in a variable, parse the `typeset -p` output, then put the value back
- accessing the last array value can be accomplished via `array[-1]` (requires `bash 4.3+`)

This also comes in at a (relatively) blazing speed of ~1.6 seconds (`ubuntu/bash`):

```
$ lastv="${a[-1]}"
$ a[-1]=""
$ typeset -p a | tail -c 40 |  awk -F'[][]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
9999999
$ a[-1]="${lastv}"
```

---

**Function:**

This gives us the following `isDense()` function:

**initial function**

```
unset -f isDense

isDense() {
  local last=$(typeset -p a | tail -c 40 | awk '{delim="[][]"; split($NF,arr,delim); print arr[2]}')
  [[ "${#a[@]}" = 0 || "${#a[@]}" -ne "${last}" ]]
}
```

**latest function** (variable=last array value)

```
unset -f isDense

isDense() {
  local lastv="${a[-1]}"
  a[-1]=""
  local last=$(typeset -p a | tail -c 40 | awk -F'[][]' '{print $(NF-1)}')
  [[ "${#a[@]}" = 0 || "${#a[@]}" -ne "${last}" ]]
  rc=$?
  a[-1]="${lastv}"
  return "${rc}"
}
```

---

**Benchmark:**

- from the question (minus the 4th test - I got tired of waiting to repopulate my 10-million entry array) which means ...
- keep in mind the benchmark/test is calling `isDense()` 3x times
- ran each function a few times in `ubuntu/bash` and these were the best times ...

Socowi's function:

```
real    0m11.717s
user    0m9.486s
sys     0m1.982s
```

oguz ismail's function:

```
real    0m10.450s
user    0m9.899s
sys     0m0.546s
```

My initial `typeset|tail-c|awk` function:

```
real    0m4.514s
user    0m3.574s
sys     0m1.442s
```

Latest test (variable=last array value)  with Socowi's `declare|tr|tail-n` function:

```
real    0m5.306s
user    0m4.130s
sys     0m2.670s
```

Latest test (variable=last array value) with original `typeset|tail-c|awk` function:

```
real    0m4.305s
user    0m3.247s
sys     0m1.761s
```

Comment: Interesting. Even though `typeset -p a` has to print more than `echo "${!a[*]}"` the former takes only a fraction of the time of the latter in the case of `a=($(seq ...))`. However, with longer values, `typeset` becomes slower and slower while `${!a[*]}` is only affected by the number of entries. Try `a=($(seq -f $(yes|tr -d \\n|head -c999)%f 999999)); time typeset -p a >/dev/null; time true "${!a[@]}"`. But the main problem is, that `awk` might parse the values instead of indices, for instance in the case of `a=([1]='[0]')`.

Comment: sure re: speed ... *it depends* ... then again, who in their right mind would (realistically) expect 'great' performance from a 10+million entry `bash` array?!?!?! :-) as for the `awk` parsing issue ... I've modified the logic to address an issue of brackets in the array value ...

Comment: The new `awk` script to extract the last element can be tricked too. It returns `0` for `a=([1]=' [0]')`. Making this robust would require parsing bash quotes, including `"…"`, `'…'`, and `$'…'`. But even then `[lastIndex]="lastValue")` had to be shorter than 100 characters. I found an alternative for bash 4.2 and higher: `last=("${a[-1]}"); last=$(declare -p last); last="${last#*=*0}n"; last=$(declare -p a | head -c -${#last} | tr \[ \\n | tail -n 1)`. This is only a bit slower than `tail -c100 | awk` (5.0s instead of 4.7s for the benchmark) but safe.

Comment: If you can modify array `a` temporarily and have bash 4.3 or higher, my previous suggestion can be drastically improved: `tmp=${a[-1]}; a[-1]=; last=$(declare -p a | tr \[ \\n | tail -n 1); last=${last%]*}; a[-1]=$tmp`. This takes only 2.0s for the benchmark and is also more portable since it doesn't require `head -c` (which is not specified by posix).

Comment: For those who are wondering why `typeset/declare -p a` is faster than `${!a[*]}`: Both are implemented by iterating over the array, but `declare` stores the result in a `char*` buffer while `${!` uses `make_word_list` which creates a linked list, which is then reversed, and then converted into `char *`. So the latter iterates the same array at least three times. Interestingly, this procedure is the same for `[*]` and `[@]`. If you write something like `for i in "${!a[@]}"`, bash will create a wordlist, convert it into a single string, and then parse that string again into a wordlist.

Comment: I came across the `a[-1]` construct last night, slept on it, came up with the idea - save the last value in a variable, clear, parse, reset - just to find your same comment/approach this morning :-) updated the answer with timings from a ubuntu vm, also added results of running 2 new functions using a variable to hold the last array value ... your suggested function (`declare/tr/tail-n`) ... my previous function (`typeset/tail-c/awk`)

Comment: Using `tail -c` will cause your function to break if the final value (or index) is sufficiently long. Since `typeset -p` outputs bash syntax the only safe way to process the output is by parsing bash's grammar. Consider `foo=(a b c); foo+=("$(typeset -p foo)")` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
isDense() {
  local -rn array="$1"
  ((${#array[@]})) || return 0
  local -ai indices=("${!array[@]}")
  ((indices[-1] + 1 == ${#array[@]}))
}
```

To follow the self-contained call convention:

```sh
test() {
  local result
  isDense "$1" && result=dense || result=sparse 
  [[ "$result" = "$2" ]] ||
  echo "Test in line $BASH_LINENO failed: $2 array considered $result"
}

a=(); test a dense
a=(''); test a dense
a=(x x x); test a dense

a=([1]=x); test a sparse
a=([1]=); test a sparse
a=([0]=x [2]=x); test a sparse
a=([4]=x [5]=x [6]=x); test a sparse
a=([0]=x [3]=x [4]=x [13]=x); test a sparse
```