# Bash - Get last index of array

Tags: arrays, bash

In Bash how can one get the last index of an array?

This works: `$((${#array[@]} - 1))` but is not very pretty.
To get the last element of an array one can do `${myarray[-1]}` is there a similar option for index?

Comment: `declare -i index; index=${#array[@]}-1; echo $index`?

Comment: @Cyrus not the way to get last index with sparse array.

Comment: take a look at this [Q&A re: is array sparse/dense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68792681/7366100); part of the req is to find the last index; Socowi's answer refers to a custom builtin that could be modified to return the last index; my answer, along with a slew of comments, looks at a few ideas for finding the last index (ie, basically parsing the output from `typeset -p`); keep in mind we were looking at performance related issues for **large** arrays; for (relatively) small arrays any of the ideas presented at that link would likely be sufficient for this OP's req

Comment: should probably update the question to verify if this is (not) an associative array; assuming a (relatively) small (associative) array, one brute force idea: `printf "%s\n" "${!array[@]}" | sort -n | tail -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with sparse arrays that have had elements unset:

```sh
indexes=( "${!array[@]}" )
lastindex=${indexes[-1]}
```

otherwise your `$((${#array[@]} - 1))` is the way. Shell isn't pretty.

Comment: If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, it's `lastindex=${(k)array[-1]}`

Answer (score 1):

Get the last index of an array, regardless if it is sparse or not:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=([4]=foo [1]=bar [5]=cux [0]=baz)

# Capture all the indexes of the array
arrindexes=("${!array[@]}")

# Print the last index and element
last_index=${arrindexes[-1]}
printf 'Last index is: %d\n' "$last_index"
printf 'Last element at index %d is: %s\n' "$last_index" "${array[last_index]}"
```